# coturn turn server error CREATE_PERMISSION 403: Forbidden IP

Tags: webrtc, turn, peerjs, coturn

I deployed turn server using [coturn](https://github.com/coturn/coturn) with near-default configurations on ec2 instance. I was not able to connect with another peer using this turn server. It showed `iceConnectionState changed to disconnected on the connection with` error as peerjs logs on browser console and `incoming packet CREATE_PERMISSION processed, error 403: Forbidden IP` error on coturn server logs. How to fix this? (rhetorical)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case,[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44996545/why-my-turn-server-doesnt-work/67180626#67180626) answer absolutely helped me( although, it was not my error). I was setting only public dns for `external-ip` in `turnserver.conf`. I set it as public-ip/private-ip and it worked. something like below:

`external-ip=13.some.thing.229/172.some.thing.else` and now even the error made sense.